# Fortran read() reads last line twice?

Tags: file-io, fortran

So, suppose I'm trying to read in a file the length of which I don't know before hand. We can use iostat and a while loop to break when we need to, but I'm having an issue with this. Namely, the code I've written reads the last line twice. I'm sure there is an obvious solution, but I can't seem to figure it out. I don't really understand how either the read() or iostat functions work entirely (I'm pretty new at fortran), but I can't glean much from documentation so I'm hoping someone here can help.

Here is the (relevant bit of) code I've written:

```
filename = 'test.txt' 
iostat_1 = 0 
iostat_2 = 0 
open(newunit = lun, file = filename, status = 'old', iostat = iostat_1) 
if (iostat_1 == 0) then 
    do while(iostat_2 == 0)             
        if(iostat_2 == 0) then 
            read(lun,*,iostat = iostat_2) dum, real_1,real_2,int_1                   
            print *, dum, real_1,real_2,int_1                  
        endif
    enddo
endif
```

So, supposing my input file is

```
1 1.0 1.0 1
2 2.0 2.0 1 
3 3.0 3.0 1
4 4.0 4.0 4
```

Then the output to the terminal from the print statement will be

```
1 1.0 1.0 1
2 2.0 2.0 1 
3 3.0 3.0 1
4 4.0 4.0 4 
4 4.0 4.0 4
```

So keep in mind the following: The main purpose here is to be able to read in a file with an arbitrary number of lines. I'm not interested in a solution involving reading the number of lines first.

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE Okay I just solved the problem. That being said, I'm wondering if there is a solution less clumsy than mine. Here is what I did to fix the issue**

```
! Body of ReInsert
filename = 'rpriov3.dat' 
iostat_1 = 0 
iostat_2 = 0 
open(newunit = lun, file = filename, status = 'old', iostat = iostat_1) 
if (iostat_1 == 0) then 
    do while(iostat_2 == 0)             
        if(iostat_2 == 0) then 
            read(lun,*,iostat = iostat_2) dum, real_1,real_2,int_1   
            if(iostat_2 == 0) then !<---- Added this nested if statement
                print *, dum, real_1,real_2,int_1   
            endif                
            print *, iostat_2                 
        endif
    enddo
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, when you set an `iostat` parameter, the `read` command doesn't overwrite the variables it asks for.

Your solution is, as you already noticed, somewhat convoluted.

Firstly:

```
do while (condition)
    if (condition) then
        ...
    end if
end do
```

In this case, the inner `if` statement is complete surplus. The loop doesn't run unless `condition` is true, so unless the evaluation of `condition` itself doesn't change the result <sup>1)</sup>, the `if` clause will always be executed.

The second thing I'd look at is: What should happen if the `open` fails? In most cases, I want to print an error and quit:

```
open(..., iostat=ios)

if (ios /= 0) then
    print*, "Error opening file"
    STOP 1
end if

do while (...)
    ...
end do
```

Even if you don't want to exit the program in case of an error in `open`, there are usually ways to make the code more readable than eternal nesting. For example, you could ask the user for a filename again and again (in its own loop) for a file name, until either the file opens, or the user enters some quit message.

```
ios = 1
do while (ios /= 0)
    write(*, *, advance='no') "Enter filename (or 'quit') :"
    read(*, *) filename

    if ( trim(filename) == "quit" ) STOP

    open(newunit=lun, file=filename, ..., iostat=ios)
end do
```

Finally there's the most inner `if` block. Since you want to exit the loop anyway when you reach an error, you can use the `exit` statement inside a loop to exit it immediately without executing the rest of the loop block:

```
do
    read(..., iostat=ios) ...
    if (ios /= 0) exit
    print *, ....
end do
```

This is an infinite loop with an explicit `exit` as soon as it encounters a read error (usually, but not necessarily an EOF). Since the `print` statement is after the `exit`, it won't be executed in case of such an error.

<sup>1)</sup> What I mean by that is something like this C snippet `i++ < 10`, which both tests `i` against `10` *and* increments it.